# when menu has specific class add submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu

Hello I want to make a menu in wordpress. When menu item has class `'category'` then add to this item submenu. How I can do it? I tried like this, but it only add class.

```
 add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'my_special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item )
{
    if($item->title == 'kategorie' )
    {
        $classes[] ='special-class';

    }
    var_dump($item->title);
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need wordpress Menu Walker for this. See Example from here.

[Demo Tutorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output)

Comment: Can you help me with this. I'm not so advanced in wordpress.

Comment: Are you hosting your site in local server or live server?

Comment: I'm hosting it in local.